# Running into problem displaying new items in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have been working on coding a frogger like game in pygame. To do this I need to have logs/items the player can land on to traverse to the other side of the screen. I am attempting to make these logs spawn at a random width of either 75, 150, or 225 pixels. The left spawning mechanism has been working, but oddly the right is creating logs that are much bigger than what is supposed to spawn. Any help would be greatly appreciated as to how to ensure these logs spawn at the correct width.

Here is my code so far:

```
import sys, pygame, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen_height = 750
screen_width = 1200
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Frogger")
FPS = 200

player = pygame.image.load('frog.bmp')
player_rect = player.get_rect()
player_rect.left = 300 + 11
player_rect.top = screen_height - 68

not_in_ocean = False

#For player movement
up_movements = 0
down_movements = 0
left_movements = 0 
right_movements = 0
up_movement = False
down_movement = False
left_movement = False
right_movement = False

x_logs = [0, 600]
y_logs = [74, 149, 224, 299, 374, 449, 524, 599] 
list_log_width = [1, 2, 3]
log_height = 74
logs_created = []
log_speeds = []
for y in y_logs:
    log_speeds.append(random.randint(1,3))


class Log():

    def __init__(self, x, y, direction, log_width, speed):
        self.direction = direction
        self.drew_new_log = False
        self.log_width = log_width
        self.speed = speed
        self.log = pygame.Rect(x, y, log_width * 75, log_height)
        self.log_length = random.randint(0,2)
        self.y_index = y_logs.index(self.log.y)

    def move_log(self):
        if self.direction == 'right':
            self.log.x += self.speed
            self.log.right += self.speed
        if self.direction == 'left':
            self.log.x -= self.speed
            self.log.right -= self.speed

    def draw_log(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (153, 102, 0), self.log)


    def delete_log(self, item):
        logs_created.remove(item)

    def draw_new_logs(self): # To address the issue of infinitely spawning in logs, put the if statements in the main game loop and only have it run this method if it meets the requirements
        if self.direction == 'right' and self.drew_new_log == False:
            if self.log.right  > screen_width:
                logs_created.append(Log((-75 * list_log_width[self.log_length]) + 1, self.log.y, 'right', list_log_width[self.log_length], log_speeds[self.y_index]))
                self.drew_new_log = True
        if self.direction == 'left' and self.drew_new_log == False:
            if self.log.left < 0:
                logs_created.append(Log(screen_width - 1, self.log.y, 'left', list_log_width[self.log_length], log_speeds[self.y_index]))
                self.drew_new_log = True

for x in x_logs:
    for y in y_logs:
        for speed in log_speeds:
            log_length = random.randint(0, 2)
            if (y_logs.index(y) % 2) == 0: 
                logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'left', list_log_width[log_length], log_speeds[y_logs.index(y)]))#list_log_width[log_length], speed))
            else:
                logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'right', list_log_width[log_length], log_speeds[y_logs.index(y)])) #list_log_width[log_length], speed)) 


while True:
    screen.fill((0, 119, 190))
    starting_area = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (32, 178, 170), (0, 675, screen_width, screen_height / 10))
    finish_area = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (32, 178, 170), (0,0, screen_width, screen_height / 10))
    ocean = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 119, 190), (0, screen_height / 10, screen_width, screen_height *0.8))

    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

    not_in_ocean = False


    for log in logs_created:
        log.draw_log()
        log.move_log()
        log.draw_new_logs()
        print(log.log_width*75)


        if log.direction == 'right':
            if log.log.centerx - ((log.log_width * 75) / 2) > screen_width:
                log.delete_log(log)
        if log.direction == 'left':
            if (log.log.right) < 0:# + (log.log_width * 75)) < 0:
                log.delete_log(log)


        if player_rect.colliderect(log.log):
            not_in_ocean = True
            if log.log_width == 3:

                if abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.right) > abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.left) and abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.left) < abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.centerx):
                    #Put the player on the left side
                    player_rect.centerx = log.log.left + 37.5

                if abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.centerx) < abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.right) and abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.centerx) < abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.left):
                    #Put the player in the middle
                    player_rect.centerx = log.log.centerx

                if abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.right) < abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.left) and abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.centerx) > abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.right):
                    #Put the player on the right side
                    player_rect.centerx = log.log.right - 37.5

            if log.log_width == 2:
                if abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.right) > abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.left):
                    #Put the player on the left side
                    player_rect.centerx = log.log.left + 37.5

                if abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.right) < abs(player_rect.centerx - log.log.left):
                    #Put the player on the right side
                    player_rect.centerx = log.log.right - 37.5

            if log.log_width == 1:
                player_rect.centerx = log.log.centerx

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                        player_rect.centerx += 75
                    if event.key == K_LEFT:
                        player_rect.x -= 75
                    if event.key == K_UP:
                        player_rect.y -= 75
                    if event.key == K_DOWN:
                        player_rect.y += 75


            if log.direction == 'right':
                player_rect.x += log_speeds[log.y_index]
            if log.direction == 'left':
                player_rect.x -= log_speeds[log.y_index]
        elif starting_area.colliderect(player_rect) or finish_area.colliderect(player_rect):
            not_in_ocean = True

    #Gameover mechanism
    if not_in_ocean == False:
        player_rect.left = 300 + 11
        player_rect.top = screen_height - 68

    screen.blit(player, player_rect)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                down_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                left_movement = True
            elif event.key == K_RIGHT:
                right_movement = True

        #Movements
    if up_movement == True:
        if player_rect.top > 11:
            if up_movements < 75:
                player_rect.y -= 15
                up_movements += 15
            else:
                up_movements = 0
                up_movement = False
        else:
            up_movement = False
            up_movements = 0
    if down_movement == True:
        if player_rect.bottom <= screen_height - 11:
            if down_movements < 75:
                player_rect.y += 15
                down_movements += 15
            else:
                down_movements = 0
                down_movement = False
        else:
            down_movement = False
            down_movements = 0

    if left_movement == True:
        if player_rect.left > 11:
            if left_movements < 75:
                player_rect.x -= 15
                left_movements += 15
            else:
                left_movements = 0
                left_movement = False
    if right_movement == True:
        if player_rect.right <= screen_width - 11:
            if right_movements < 75:
                player_rect.x += 15
                right_movements += 15
            else:
                right_movements = 0
                right_movement = False

    if player_rect.left < 0 or player_rect.right > screen_width:
        #Gameover
        player_rect.left = 300 + 11
        player_rect.top = screen_height - 68


    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: The logs are not to long, but multiple logs are overlapping and appear to be one large log

Comment: @Rabbid76 Any ideas as to how to resolve this error and fix the spawning method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create far to much logs. You create one log for each speed in `log_speeds`

> ```py
> for x in x_logs:
>    for y in y_logs:
>        for speed in log_speeds:
>            # [...]
> ```

Use [``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) to select a random element from `log_speeds`:

```py
for x in x_logs:
    for y in y_logs:
        speed = random.choice(log_speeds)
        log_length = random.randint(0, 2)
        if (y_logs.index(y) % 2) == 0: 
            logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'left', list_log_width[log_length], log_speeds[y_logs.index(y)]))#list_log_width[log_length], speed))
        else:
            logs_created.append(Log(x, y, 'right', list_log_width[log_length], log_speeds[y_logs.index(y)])) #list_log_width[log_length], speed))
```

Do not delete elements from a list while you iterate trough the list. Iterate through a copy of the list (logs_created[:]). See [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). but remove the elements from the original list when the rectangle has left the screen completely:

```py
while True:
    # [...]

    for log in logs_created[:]:
        log.draw_log()
        log.move_log()
        log.draw_new_logs()

        if log.direction == 'right':
            if log.log.left > screen_width:
                log.delete_log(log)
        if log.direction == 'left':
            if log.log.right < 0:
                log.delete_log(log)

        # [...]
```